# How can I build a tree from a normalized tree list

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a normalized tree list:

```js
const normalizedTree = {
  0: {
    id: 0,
    title: '(Root)',
    childIds: [1, 43, 47],
  },
  1: {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Earth',
    childIds: [2, 10, 19, 27, 35],
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Africa',
    childIds: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Botswana',
    childIds: [],
  },
  4: {
    id: 4,
    title: 'Egypt',
    childIds: [],
  },
  5: {
    id: 5,
    title: 'Kenya',
    childIds: [],
  },
  6: {
    id: 6,
    title: 'Madagascar',
    childIds: [],
  },
  7: {
    id: 7,
    title: 'Morocco',
    childIds: [],
  },
  8: {
    id: 8,
    title: 'Nigeria',
    childIds: [],
  },
  9: {
    id: 9,
    title: 'South Africa',
    childIds: [],
  },
  10: {
    id: 10,
    title: 'Americas',
    childIds: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
  },
  11: {
    id: 11,
    title: 'Argentina',
    childIds: [],
  },
  12: {
    id: 12,
    title: 'Brazil',
    childIds: [],
  },
  13: {
    id: 13,
    title: 'Barbados',
    childIds: [],
  },
  14: {
    id: 14,
    title: 'Canada',
    childIds: [],
  },
  15: {
    id: 15,
    title: 'Jamaica',
    childIds: [],
  },
  16: {
    id: 16,
    title: 'Mexico',
    childIds: [],
  },
  17: {
    id: 17,
    title: 'Trinidad and Tobago',
    childIds: [],
  },
  18: {
    id: 18,
    title: 'Venezuela',
    childIds: [],
  },
  19: {
    id: 19,
    title: 'Asia',
    childIds: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
  },
  20: {
    id: 20,
    title: 'China',
    childIds: [],
  },
  21: {
    id: 21,
    title: 'Hong Kong',
    childIds: [],
  },
  22: {
    id: 22,
    title: 'India',
    childIds: [],
  },
  23: {
    id: 23,
    title: 'Singapore',
    childIds: [],
  },
  24: {
    id: 24,
    title: 'South Korea',
    childIds: [],
  },
  25: {
    id: 25,
    title: 'Thailand',
    childIds: [],
  },
  26: {
    id: 26,
    title: 'Vietnam',
    childIds: [],
  },
  27: {
    id: 27,
    title: 'Europe',
    childIds: [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
  },
  28: {
    id: 28,
    title: 'Croatia',
    childIds: [],
  },
  29: {
    id: 29,
    title: 'France',
    childIds: [],
  },
  30: {
    id: 30,
    title: 'Germany',
    childIds: [],
  },
  31: {
    id: 31,
    title: 'Italy',
    childIds: [],
  },
  32: {
    id: 32,
    title: 'Portugal',
    childIds: [],
  },
  33: {
    id: 33,
    title: 'Spain',
    childIds: [],
  },
  34: {
    id: 34,
    title: 'Turkey',
    childIds: [],
  },
  35: {
    id: 35,
    title: 'Oceania',
    childIds: [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42],
  },
  36: {
    id: 36,
    title: 'Australia',
    childIds: [],
  },
  37: {
    id: 37,
    title: 'Bora Bora (French Polynesia)',
    childIds: [],
  },
  38: {
    id: 38,
    title: 'Easter Island (Chile)',
    childIds: [],
  },
  39: {
    id: 39,
    title: 'Fiji',
    childIds: [],
  },
  40: {
    id: 40,
    title: 'Hawaii (the USA)',
    childIds: [],
  },
  41: {
    id: 41,
    title: 'New Zealand',
    childIds: [],
  },
  42: {
    id: 42,
    title: 'Vanuatu',
    childIds: [],
  },
  43: {
    id: 43,
    title: 'Moon',
    childIds: [44, 45, 46],
  },
  44: {
    id: 44,
    title: 'Rheita',
    childIds: [],
  },
  45: {
    id: 45,
    title: 'Piccolomini',
    childIds: [],
  },
  46: {
    id: 46,
    title: 'Tycho',
    childIds: [],
  },
  47: {
    id: 47,
    title: 'Mars',
    childIds: [48, 49],
  },
  48: {
    id: 48,
    title: 'Corn Town',
    childIds: [],
  },
  49: {
    id: 49,
    title: 'Green Hill',
    childIds: [],
  },
}
```

And I am trying to build out a tree from it as in:

```js
const tree = {
  id: 0,
  title: '(Root)',
  childPlaces: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Earth',
      childPlaces: [
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Africa',
          childPlaces: [
            {
              id: 3,
              title: 'Botswana',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 4,
              title: 'Egypt',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 5,
              title: 'Kenya',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 6,
              title: 'Madagascar',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 7,
              title: 'Morocco',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 8,
              title: 'Nigeria',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 9,
              title: 'South Africa',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 10,
          title: 'Americas',
          childPlaces: [
            {
              id: 11,
              title: 'Argentina',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 12,
              title: 'Brazil',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 13,
              title: 'Barbados',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 14,
              title: 'Canada',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 15,
              title: 'Jamaica',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 16,
              title: 'Mexico',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 17,
              title: 'Trinidad and Tobago',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 18,
              title: 'Venezuela',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 19,
          title: 'Asia',
          childPlaces: [
            {
              id: 20,
              title: 'China',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 21,
              title: 'Hong Kong',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 22,
              title: 'India',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 23,
              title: 'Singapore',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 24,
              title: 'South Korea',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 25,
              title: 'Thailand',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 26,
              title: 'Vietnam',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 27,
          title: 'Europe',
          childPlaces: [
            {
              id: 28,
              title: 'Croatia',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 29,
              title: 'France',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 30,
              title: 'Germany',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 31,
              title: 'Italy',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 32,
              title: 'Portugal',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 33,
              title: 'Spain',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 34,
              title: 'Turkey',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 35,
          title: 'Oceania',
          childPlaces: [
            {
              id: 36,
              title: 'Australia',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 37,
              title: 'Bora Bora (French Polynesia)',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 38,
              title: 'Easter Island (Chile)',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 39,
              title: 'Fiji',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 40,
              title: 'Hawaii (the USA)',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 41,
              title: 'New Zealand',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
            {
              id: 42,
              title: 'Vanuatu',
              childPlaces: [],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 43,
      title: 'Moon',
      childPlaces: [
        {
          id: 44,
          title: 'Rheita',
          childPlaces: [],
        },
        {
          id: 45,
          title: 'Piccolomini',
          childPlaces: [],
        },
        {
          id: 46,
          title: 'Tycho',
          childPlaces: [],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 47,
      title: 'Mars',
      childPlaces: [
        {
          id: 48,
          title: 'Corn Town',
          childPlaces: [],
        },
        {
          id: 49,
          title: 'Green Hill',
          childPlaces: [],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

Here is my attempt:

```js
function buildTree(normalizedTree) {
  const root = {
    id: 0,
    title: '(Root)',
    childPlaces: [],
  }

  let parent = root

  for (const node of Object.values(normalizedTree)) {
    const newNode = {
      id: node.id,
      title: node.title,
      childPlaces: [],
    }

    if (normalizedTree[parent.id].childIds.includes(node.id)) {
      parent.childPlaces.push(newNode)
    }
  }

  return root
}
```

The current solution only outputs the first level of the tree:

```js
{
  id: 0,
  title: '(Root)',
  childPlaces: [
    { id: 1, title: 'Earth', childPlaces: [] },
    { id: 43, title: 'Moon', childPlaces: [] },
    { id: 47, title: 'Mars', childPlaces: [] }
  ]
}
```

I realized I needed to advance the `parent` pointer somewhere in my algorithms but I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: I think you will find [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73251416/633183) to be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a recursive method - start at the root ID and work through its `childIds` and so on, that way each time you're iterating over an ID you'll have a reference to the parent object and can put it in the right `childPlaces` array. With your current approach, unless you've created some of the nested structure already and can identify the parent from an ID, you can't really do much with a created node.

```js
const normalizedTree={0:{id:0,title:"(Root)",childIds:[1,43,47]},1:{id:1,title:"Earth",childIds:[2,10,19,27,35]},2:{id:2,title:"Africa",childIds:[3,4,5,6,7,8,9]},3:{id:3,title:"Botswana",childIds:[]},4:{id:4,title:"Egypt",childIds:[]},5:{id:5,title:"Kenya",childIds:[]},6:{id:6,title:"Madagascar",childIds:[]},7:{id:7,title:"Morocco",childIds:[]},8:{id:8,title:"Nigeria",childIds:[]},9:{id:9,title:"South Africa",childIds:[]},10:{id:10,title:"Americas",childIds:[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]},11:{id:11,title:"Argentina",childIds:[]},12:{id:12,title:"Brazil",childIds:[]},13:{id:13,title:"Barbados",childIds:[]},14:{id:14,title:"Canada",childIds:[]},15:{id:15,title:"Jamaica",childIds:[]},16:{id:16,title:"Mexico",childIds:[]},17:{id:17,title:"Trinidad and Tobago",childIds:[]},18:{id:18,title:"Venezuela",childIds:[]},19:{id:19,title:"Asia",childIds:[20,21,22,23,24,25,26]},20:{id:20,title:"China",childIds:[]},21:{id:21,title:"Hong Kong",childIds:[]},22:{id:22,title:"India",childIds:[]},23:{id:23,title:"Singapore",childIds:[]},24:{id:24,title:"South Korea",childIds:[]},25:{id:25,title:"Thailand",childIds:[]},26:{id:26,title:"Vietnam",childIds:[]},27:{id:27,title:"Europe",childIds:[28,29,30,31,32,33,34]},28:{id:28,title:"Croatia",childIds:[]},29:{id:29,title:"France",childIds:[]},30:{id:30,title:"Germany",childIds:[]},31:{id:31,title:"Italy",childIds:[]},32:{id:32,title:"Portugal",childIds:[]},33:{id:33,title:"Spain",childIds:[]},34:{id:34,title:"Turkey",childIds:[]},35:{id:35,title:"Oceania",childIds:[36,37,38,39,40,41,42]},36:{id:36,title:"Australia",childIds:[]},37:{id:37,title:"Bora Bora (French Polynesia)",childIds:[]},38:{id:38,title:"Easter Island (Chile)",childIds:[]},39:{id:39,title:"Fiji",childIds:[]},40:{id:40,title:"Hawaii (the USA)",childIds:[]},41:{id:41,title:"New Zealand",childIds:[]},42:{id:42,title:"Vanuatu",childIds:[]},43:{id:43,title:"Moon",childIds:[44,45,46]},44:{id:44,title:"Rheita",childIds:[]},45:{id:45,title:"Piccolomini",childIds:[]},46:{id:46,title:"Tycho",childIds:[]},47:{id:47,title:"Mars",childIds:[48,49]},48:{id:48,title:"Corn Town",childIds:[]},49:{id:49,title:"Green Hill",childIds:[]}};

const buildTree = (id) => {
  const { title, childIds } = normalizedTree[id];
  return { id, title, childPlaces: childIds.map(buildTree) };
};
const tree = buildTree(0); // root ID
console.log(tree);
```

Doing it without recursion would be uglier. I suppose you could map the `normalizedTree` to another one, where each object has a `childPlaces` array instead of `childIds`, then iterate over the original tree and push each child ID to the new tree's array, then finally take the root object to get the structure you want.

```js
const normalizedTree={0:{id:0,title:"(Root)",childIds:[1,43,47]},1:{id:1,title:"Earth",childIds:[2,10,19,27,35]},2:{id:2,title:"Africa",childIds:[3,4,5,6,7,8,9]},3:{id:3,title:"Botswana",childIds:[]},4:{id:4,title:"Egypt",childIds:[]},5:{id:5,title:"Kenya",childIds:[]},6:{id:6,title:"Madagascar",childIds:[]},7:{id:7,title:"Morocco",childIds:[]},8:{id:8,title:"Nigeria",childIds:[]},9:{id:9,title:"South Africa",childIds:[]},10:{id:10,title:"Americas",childIds:[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]},11:{id:11,title:"Argentina",childIds:[]},12:{id:12,title:"Brazil",childIds:[]},13:{id:13,title:"Barbados",childIds:[]},14:{id:14,title:"Canada",childIds:[]},15:{id:15,title:"Jamaica",childIds:[]},16:{id:16,title:"Mexico",childIds:[]},17:{id:17,title:"Trinidad and Tobago",childIds:[]},18:{id:18,title:"Venezuela",childIds:[]},19:{id:19,title:"Asia",childIds:[20,21,22,23,24,25,26]},20:{id:20,title:"China",childIds:[]},21:{id:21,title:"Hong Kong",childIds:[]},22:{id:22,title:"India",childIds:[]},23:{id:23,title:"Singapore",childIds:[]},24:{id:24,title:"South Korea",childIds:[]},25:{id:25,title:"Thailand",childIds:[]},26:{id:26,title:"Vietnam",childIds:[]},27:{id:27,title:"Europe",childIds:[28,29,30,31,32,33,34]},28:{id:28,title:"Croatia",childIds:[]},29:{id:29,title:"France",childIds:[]},30:{id:30,title:"Germany",childIds:[]},31:{id:31,title:"Italy",childIds:[]},32:{id:32,title:"Portugal",childIds:[]},33:{id:33,title:"Spain",childIds:[]},34:{id:34,title:"Turkey",childIds:[]},35:{id:35,title:"Oceania",childIds:[36,37,38,39,40,41,42]},36:{id:36,title:"Australia",childIds:[]},37:{id:37,title:"Bora Bora (French Polynesia)",childIds:[]},38:{id:38,title:"Easter Island (Chile)",childIds:[]},39:{id:39,title:"Fiji",childIds:[]},40:{id:40,title:"Hawaii (the USA)",childIds:[]},41:{id:41,title:"New Zealand",childIds:[]},42:{id:42,title:"Vanuatu",childIds:[]},43:{id:43,title:"Moon",childIds:[44,45,46]},44:{id:44,title:"Rheita",childIds:[]},45:{id:45,title:"Piccolomini",childIds:[]},46:{id:46,title:"Tycho",childIds:[]},47:{id:47,title:"Mars",childIds:[48,49]},48:{id:48,title:"Corn Town",childIds:[]},49:{id:49,title:"Green Hill",childIds:[]}};

const buildNormalizedTreeWithChildPlaces = () => {
  const newTree = {};
  for (const node of Object.values(normalizedTree)) {
    const newNode = {
      id: node.id,
      title: node.title,
      childPlaces: [],
    };
    newTree[node.id] = newNode;
  }
  for (const [id, node] of Object.entries(normalizedTree)) {
    for (const childId of node.childIds) {
      newTree[id].childPlaces.push(newTree[childId]);
    }
  }
  return newTree;
};
const tree = buildNormalizedTreeWithChildPlaces();
console.log(tree[0]); // root ID
```

Comment: wow didn't know the recursive approach is so simple and elegant. but do you happen to know how we can fix my iterative approach ?

Comment: Possible, but uglier, you'd have to iterate over everything twice

Comment: thanks! your solution is by far the most elegant!

Answer (score 0):

The following allow you to create the tree with 1 iteration.

```js
const normalizedTree={0:{id:0,title:"(Root)",childIds:[1,43,47]},1:{id:1,title:"Earth",childIds:[2,10,19,27,35]},2:{id:2,title:"Africa",childIds:[3,4,5,6,7,8,9]},3:{id:3,title:"Botswana",childIds:[]},4:{id:4,title:"Egypt",childIds:[]},5:{id:5,title:"Kenya",childIds:[]},6:{id:6,title:"Madagascar",childIds:[]},7:{id:7,title:"Morocco",childIds:[]},8:{id:8,title:"Nigeria",childIds:[]},9:{id:9,title:"South Africa",childIds:[]},10:{id:10,title:"Americas",childIds:[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]},11:{id:11,title:"Argentina",childIds:[]},12:{id:12,title:"Brazil",childIds:[]},13:{id:13,title:"Barbados",childIds:[]},14:{id:14,title:"Canada",childIds:[]},15:{id:15,title:"Jamaica",childIds:[]},16:{id:16,title:"Mexico",childIds:[]},17:{id:17,title:"Trinidad and Tobago",childIds:[]},18:{id:18,title:"Venezuela",childIds:[]},19:{id:19,title:"Asia",childIds:[20,21,22,23,24,25,26]},20:{id:20,title:"China",childIds:[]},21:{id:21,title:"Hong Kong",childIds:[]},22:{id:22,title:"India",childIds:[]},23:{id:23,title:"Singapore",childIds:[]},24:{id:24,title:"South Korea",childIds:[]},25:{id:25,title:"Thailand",childIds:[]},26:{id:26,title:"Vietnam",childIds:[]},27:{id:27,title:"Europe",childIds:[28,29,30,31,32,33,34]},28:{id:28,title:"Croatia",childIds:[]},29:{id:29,title:"France",childIds:[]},30:{id:30,title:"Germany",childIds:[]},31:{id:31,title:"Italy",childIds:[]},32:{id:32,title:"Portugal",childIds:[]},33:{id:33,title:"Spain",childIds:[]},34:{id:34,title:"Turkey",childIds:[]},35:{id:35,title:"Oceania",childIds:[36,37,38,39,40,41,42]},36:{id:36,title:"Australia",childIds:[]},37:{id:37,title:"Bora Bora (French Polynesia)",childIds:[]},38:{id:38,title:"Easter Island (Chile)",childIds:[]},39:{id:39,title:"Fiji",childIds:[]},40:{id:40,title:"Hawaii (the USA)",childIds:[]},41:{id:41,title:"New Zealand",childIds:[]},42:{id:42,title:"Vanuatu",childIds:[]},43:{id:43,title:"Moon",childIds:[44,45,46]},44:{id:44,title:"Rheita",childIds:[]},45:{id:45,title:"Piccolomini",childIds:[]},46:{id:46,title:"Tycho",childIds:[]},47:{id:47,title:"Mars",childIds:[48,49]},48:{id:48,title:"Corn Town",childIds:[]},49:{id:49,title:"Green Hill",childIds:[]}};

function buildTree(normalizedTree, rootId) {
  const nodes = Object.values(normalizedTree);
  const nodeMap = new Map(nodes.map(node => [node.id, { ...node }]));
  
  for(let node of nodes) {
      const n = nodeMap.get(node.id); if (n == null) continue;
      n.childPlaces = n.childIds.map(childId => nodeMap.get(childId));
      delete n.childIds;
  }
  return nodeMap.get(rootId);
}
console.log(buildTree(normalizedTree, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```js
parent.childPlaces.push(newNode)
```

but it seems `parent` is always `root`.

Another approach is delaying the `childPlaces` data:

```
function buildTree(normalized)
{
  const nodesArray = Object.values(normalizedTree);
  const idNodeMap = {};
  const children = new Set();
  // generate tree nodes without their children (delay the children)
  nodesArray.forEach(node => {
    idNodeMap[node.id] = {
        id: node.id,
        title: node.title,
        childPlaces: []
    };
  });
  // add the children (delayed)
  nodesArray.forEach(node => {
    node.childIds.forEach(id => {
        const child = idNodeMap[id];
        children.add(child);
        idNodeMap[node.id]
            .childPlaces
            .push(child);
    });
  });
  // find the root
  return Object.values(idNodeMap).find(node => !children.has(node));
}
```

A simpler approach is saving the nodes in a map and take advantage of the references. It instantiates empty objects for the children, if they're not found in that map.

```js
function buildTree(normalized)
{
  const idNodesMap = {};
  const children = new Set();
  Object.values(normalizedTree)
    .forEach(node => {
      const obj = idNodesMap[node.id] ?? {};
      obj.id = node.id;
      obj.title = node.title;
      obj.childPlaces = node.childIds.map(childId => {
        const child = idNodesMap[childId] ?? {};
            idNodesMap[childId] = child;
            children.add(child);
            return child;
        });
        idNodesMap[node.id] = obj;
    });
    return Object.values(idNodesMap).find(node => !children.has(node));;
}
```

Here's a shorter solution, using recursion (it assumes the root ID is 0):

```js
function buildTree(normalized, id=0)
{
  const node = normalized[id];
  return {
    id: node.id,
    title: node.title,
    childPlaces: node.childIds.map(id => buildTree(normalized, id)),
  };
}
```