# How can i recursively group children objects under parent in an array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

I have an array of topics each linked to a parent topic. So, basically what I want to do is form an array with all the children topics nested under the parent.
So if I had an table of topics looking like this:

| id | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Topic 1 | null |
| 2 | Topic 2 | 1 |
| 3 | Topic 3 | 2 |
| 4 | Topic 4 | 2 |
| 5 | Topic 5 | 4 |

And if the json array looks like this:

```js
[
  { id: 1, name: "Topic 1", parent_id: null },
  { id: 2, name: "Topic 2", parent_id: 1 },
  { id: 3, name: "Topic 3", parent_id: 2 },
  { id: 4, name: "Topic 4", parent_id: 2 },
  { id: 5, name: "Topic 5", parent_id: 4 },
]
```

I want the output array to look like this:

```js
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Topic 1",
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Topic 2",
        children: [
          { id: 3, name: "Topic 3", children: [] },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: "Topic 4",
            children: [{ id: 5, name: "Topic 5", children: [] }],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Comment: Hi , what is the input data ? Do we have to query your table in html ? Is the data to process in json , in a list of objects ? You only talk about the wanted output but we cannot help you write the code if you don't talk about the input

Comment: I've updated the question with the input json array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**assume nothing, control everything**

A tree is a graph with parent->child relationships between the nodes. To construct this graph efficiently, we must first index the flat array of nodes -

```
{
  A => [child, child, child, ...],
  B => [child, child, ...],
  C => [...],
  ...
}
```

The input array does not need to be ordered in a specific way for this technique to work. In fact, it's important that our modules make no assumptions about the order or shape of our data. This puts the caller (you!) in control and ensures the highest degree of flexibility and reusability -

```js
import * as index from "./index.js"
import * as graph from "./graph.js"

const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "Topic 1", parent_id: null },
  { id: 2, name: "Topic 2", parent_id: 1 },
  { id: 3, name: "Topic 3", parent_id: 2 },
  { id: 4, name: "Topic 4", parent_id: 2 },
  { id: 5, name: "Topic 5", parent_id: 4 },
]

const tree = 
  graph.new(
    // create index by foreign key, node.parent_id
    index.new(data, node => node.parent_id),
    // construct node's children using primary key, node.id
    (node, children) => ({...node, children: children(node.id)})
  )

console.log(JSON.stringify(tree, null, 2))
```

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Topic 1",
    "parent_id": null,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Topic 2",
        "parent_id": 1,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Topic 3",
            "parent_id": 2,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Topic 4",
            "parent_id": 2,
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Topic 5",
                "parent_id": 4,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Did you notice how `index.new` accepts a function to declare the node's foreign key and `graph.new` uses the node's primary key? This means you can reuse these modules for nodes of any shape or arrangement, without needing to modify the module's code. Let's review `index` and `graph` now -

```js
// index.js

const empty = _ =>
  new Map

const update = (t, k, f) =>
  t.set(k, f(r.get(k)))

const append = (t, k, v) =>
  update(t, k, (a = []) => [...a, v])

const _new = (a = [], f) =>
  a.reduce((t, v) => append(t, f(v), v), empty())

export { empty, update, append, new:_new }
```

```js
// graph.js

const empty = _ =>
  {}

const _new = (i, f, root = null) => {
  const many = (a = []) =>
    a.map(v => one(v))
  const one = (v) =>
    f(v, next => many(i.get(next)))
  return many(i.get(root))
}

exports { empty, new:_new }
```

Expand and run the code below to verify the result in your own browser -

```js
const callcc = f => {
  const box = Symbol()
  try { return f(unbox => { throw {box, unbox} }) }
  catch (e) { if (e?.box == box) return e.unbox; throw e  }
}

// stacksnippets doesn't support modules yet
const module = callcc

const index = module(exports => {
  const empty = _ => new Map
  const update = (t, k, f) =>
    t.set(k, f(t.get(k)))
  const append = (t, k, v) =>
    update(t, k, (a = []) => [...a, v])
  const _new = (a = [], f) =>
    a.reduce((t, v) => append(t, f(v), v), empty())
  exports({ empty, update, append, new:_new })
})

const graph = module(exports => {
  const empty = _ => {}
  const _new = (i, f, root = null) => {
    const many = (a = []) =>
      a.map(v => one(v))
    const one = (v) =>
      f(v, next => many(i.get(next)))
    return many(i.get(root))
  }
  exports({ empty, new:_new })
})

const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "Topic 1", parent_id: null },
  { id: 2, name: "Topic 2", parent_id: 1 },
  { id: 3, name: "Topic 3", parent_id: 2 },
  { id: 4, name: "Topic 4", parent_id: 2 },
  { id: 5, name: "Topic 5", parent_id: 4 },
]

const tree = 
  graph.new(
    // create index by node.parent_id
    index.new(data, node => node.parent_id),
    // construct node's children using node.id
    (node, children) => ({...node, children: children(node.id)})
  )

console.log(JSON.stringify(tree, null, 2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the IDs that are at the root level, i.e. with no parents. For these IDs, recursively build their grouped data, similar to writing a [depth first search](https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/ODSA/Books/Everything/html/GraphTraversal.html#depth-first-search) recursion.

Here are the steps taken in the implementation below:

- Using the given data, store each ID's children to allow for an easy access during recursion. The structure looks like `{ ID -> Set of its children }`. This type of representation of a graph is also known as an [Adjacency List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list).
- Obtain IDs that are at the root level, i.e. IDs that don't have any parents. For these IDs, recursively build the grouped data using recursion on their children
- (Could be optional depending on the requirements) Keep track of the already processed IDs to avoid reprocessing

```
// Helper function, returns a map of {ID -> Set of its child IDs}
// that represents the tree structure.
function getAdjListRepr(data) {
  const adjListRepr = new Map();
  for (const entry of data) {
    if (!adjListRepr.has(entry.id)) {
      adjListRepr.set(entry.id, new Set());
    }
    if (entry.parent_id !== null) {
      if (!adjListRepr.has(entry.parent_id)) {
        adjListRepr.set(entry.parent_id, new Set());
      }
      adjListRepr.get(entry.parent_id).add(entry.id);
    }
  }
  return adjListRepr;
}

// Helper function, returns the IDs that are at the root level, i.e.
// IDs that don't have a parent.
function getRootIds(data) {
  const rootIds = [];
  for (const entry of data) {
    if (entry.parent_id === null) {
      rootIds.push(entry.id);
    }
  }
  return rootIds;
}

// Helper function, creates the grouped data for a specific
// ID using recursion on the child IDs.
function getGroupedDataForId(id, idToData, adjListRepr, alreadyProcessedIds) {
  if (!idToData.has(id) || !adjListRepr.has(id) ||
      alreadyProcessedIds.has(id)) {
    return null;
  }
  const result = idToData.get(id);
  result.children = [];
  for (const childId of adjListRepr.get(id)) {
    // Recursion
    const childIdData = getGroupedDataForId(
        /*id=*/ childId, idToData, adjListRepr, alreadyProcessedIds);
    if (childIdData !== null) {
      result.children.push(childIdData);
    }
    alreadyProcessedIds.add(childId);
  }
  alreadyProcessedIds.add(id);
  return result;
}

// Returns the final grouped data.
function getGroupedData(data) {
  // A map of ID to its data
  const idToData = new Map(data.map(entry => [entry.id, entry]));
  // Adjacency list representation of the tree
  const adjListRepr = getAdjListRepr(data);

  // Root IDs, i.e. IDs with no parent
  const rootIds = getRootIds(data);
  if (rootIds.size === 0) {
    // Invalid data
    return null;
  }
  // IDs that have been grouped with children
  const alreadyProcessedIds = new Set();
  // Final result
  const result = [];

  // Recursively add IDs
  for (const rootId of rootIds) {
    const groupedData = getGroupedDataForId(
        /*id=*/ rootId, idToData, adjListRepr, alreadyProcessedIds);
    if (groupedData !== null) {
      result.push(groupedData);
    }
  }

  return result;
}


// Test
const data = [
  {'id': 1, 'name': 'Topic 1', 'parent_id': null},
  {'id': 2, 'name': 'Topic 2', 'parent_id': 1},
  {'id': 3, 'name': 'Topic 3', 'parent_id': 2},
  {'id': 4, 'name': 'Topic 4', 'parent_id': 2},
  {'id': 5, 'name': 'Topic 5', 'parent_id': 4},
  {'id': 6, 'name': 'Topic 6', 'parent_id': null},
  {'id': 7, 'name': 'Topic 7', 'parent_id': 1},
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(getGroupedData(data)));
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!
Though I'm finding it a bit difficult to wrap my head around what exactly is happening in the above code. Could you maybe elaborate a bit on the whole solution and especially that adjMatrix bit? Thanks again!

Comment: There is a tight coupling between the graph-making function and the shape of the nodes it relies upon. This is evident by use of things like `.id`, `.parent_id`, and `.children` appearing in the code. If these properties were to change or if we need to construct a graph of different nodes, the program here would be insufficient.

Comment: @OP added some elaboration, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this with a simple recursive function and iterate from the top of your list of objects.

```
function BuildChild(data, currentChild){
//Creating current child object
var child = {};
child.id = currentChild.id;
child.name = currentChild.name;
child.children = [];

//Looking for childrens in all input data
var currentChildren = data.filter(item => item.parent_id == child.id);
if(currentChildren.length > 0){
    currentChildren.forEach(function(item){
        //Iterating threw children and calling the recursive function
        //Adding the result to our current children
        child.children.push(BuildChild(data,item));
    });
}
return child;  }
```

You can then call it while getting the "top parent" of your list :

```
BuildChild(data, data.find(child => child.parent_id == null))
```

Snippet with result :

```js
 function BuildChild(data, currentChild){
    //Creating current child object
    var child = {};
    child.id = currentChild.id;
    child.name = currentChild.name;
    child.children = [];

    //Looking for childrens in all input data
    var currentChildren = data.filter(item => item.parent_id == child.id);
    if(currentChildren.length > 0){
        currentChildren.forEach(function(item){
            //Iterating threw children and calling the recursive function
            //Adding the result to our current children
            child.children.push(BuildChild(data,item));
        });
    }
    return child;  
 }
 
 
 var data = [
  { id: 1, name: "Topic 1", parent_id: null },
  { id: 2, name: "Topic 2", parent_id: 1 },
  { id: 3, name: "Topic 3", parent_id: 2 },
  { id: 4, name: "Topic 4", parent_id: 2 },
  { id: 5, name: "Topic 5", parent_id: 4 },
]
console.log(BuildChild(data, data.find(child => child.parent_id == null)))
```

Comment: The solution is quadratic in time complexity and also assumes there's only one root (which might be okay depending on OP's problem). To cover multiple level 0 IDs, add `data.filter(entry => entry.parent_id === null).forEach(root => result.push(BuildChild(data, root)));`. Cheers