# How to flatten an object that has array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, flatten

I am trying to solve this question it needs me to flatten this object `parent` that it has `children` each parent has 2 children, and each child has 2 children and so on....

**My goal is to flatten this to one single object.**

```
const par = {
    id: 1,
    name: "parent",
    children: [{
        id: 2,
        name: "child 1",
        children:[{
            id: 4,
            name: "child 3",
            children: [],
        },{
            id: 5,
            name: "child 4 ",
        }]
    },{
        id: 3,
        name: "child 2",
        children: [{
            id: 6,
            name: "child 5",
        },{
            id: 7,
            name: "child 6",
            children: []
        }]
    }]
}
```

I tried function, but it returns an array from
[Deep Flatten JavaScript Object Recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803044/deep-flatten-javascript-object-recursively)

```
function flat(r, a) {
    let b = {};
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        if (k !== 'children') {
            b[k] = a[k];
        }
    });
    r.push(b);
    if (Array.isArray(a.children)) {
        b.children = a.children.map(function (a) { return a.id;});
        return a.children.reduce(flat, r);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: What's the expected output of the above?

Comment: thanks for reminding me let me add it to the question

Comment: Do you want as a result an array of all family members or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still owe us a description of your desired output.  But if you want something as simple as this:

```js
[
    {id: 1, name: "parent"},
    {id: 2, name: "child 1"},
    {id: 4, name: "child 3"},
    {id: 5, name: "child 4"},
    {id: 3, name: "child 2"},
    {id: 6, name: "child 5"},
    {id: 7, name: "child 6"}
]
```

Then a depth-first recursive function can be as simple as this:

```js
const flatten = ({children = [], ...rest}) => [rest, ...children .flatMap (flatten)]

const par = {id: 1, name: "parent", children: [{id: 2, name: "child 1", children: [{id: 4, name: "child 3", children: []}, {id: 5, name: "child 4 ", }]}, {id: 3, name: "child 2", children: [{id: 6, name: "child 5", }, {id: 7, name: "child 6", children: []}]}]}

console .log (flatten (par))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If you wanted to include a `parentId` field, using `null` for root-level objects, it's only slightly more complex:

```js
const flatten = ({id, children = [], ...rest}, parentId = null) => [
  {id, ...rest, parentId}, ...children .flatMap (c => flatten(c, id))
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an effective technique using a recursive generator `flat` -

```js
function *flat({ children = [], ...t }, parentId = null) {
  yield { ...t, parentId }
  for (const child of children)
    yield *flat(child, t.id)
}

const par = {id: 1,name: "parent",children: [{id: 2,name: "child 1",children:[{id: 4,name: "child 3",children: [],},{id: 5,name: "child 4 ",}]},{id: 3,name: "child 2",children: [{id: 6,name: "child 5",},{id: 7,name: "child 6",children: []}]}]}

console.log(Array.from(flat(par)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

You can collect all the results of a generator using `Array.from` -

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "parent",
    "parentId": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "child 1",
    "parentId": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "child 3",
    "parentId": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "child 4 ",
    "parentId": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "child 2",
    "parentId": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "child 5",
    "parentId": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "child 6",
    "parentId": 3
  }
]
```

Or you can simply iterate thru the generator's result directly -

```js
for (const flatNode of flat(par)) {
  // do something with flatNode ...
}
```

See this [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73251416/633183) for a technique to convert the flat tree back to a recursive tree or graph.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
function flatTree(tree, parentId = null) {
  const { id, name, children } = tree;
  const result = [{ id, name, parentId }];
  if (Array.isArray(children)) {
    children.forEach((child) => {
      result.push(...flatTree(child, id));
    });
  }
  return result;
}

const par = {
  id: 1,
  name: "parent",
  children: [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "child 1",
      children: [
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "child 3",
          children: [],
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "child 4 ",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "child 2",
      children: [
        {
          id: 6,
          name: "child 5",
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          name: "child 6",
          children: [],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

console.log(flatTree(par));

/**
 * Output:
 * [
  { id: 1, name: 'parent', parentId: null },
  { id: 2, name: 'child 1', parentId: 1 },
  { id: 4, name: 'child 3', parentId: 2 },
  { id: 5, name: 'child 4 ', parentId: 2 },
  { id: 3, name: 'child 2', parentId: 1 },
  { id: 6, name: 'child 5', parentId: 3 },
  { id: 7, name: 'child 6', parentId: 3 }
]
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). Reinventing the wheel is typically not as bug-free, flexible or maintainable as using a battle-tested library!

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import objectScan from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-scan@18.4.0/lib/index.min.js';

const par = { id: 1, name: 'parent', children: [{ id: 2, name: 'child 1', children: [{ id: 4, name: 'child 3', children: [] }, { id: 5, name: 'child 4 ' }] }, { id: 3, name: 'child 2', children: [{ id: 6, name: 'child 5' }, { id: 7, name: 'child 6', children: [] }] }] };

const fn = objectScan(['**{children[*]}.id'], {
  rtn: ({ parent: { id, name } }) => ({ id, name })
});

const r = fn(par);
console.log(r);
/* => [
  { id: 7, name: 'child 6' },
  { id: 6, name: 'child 5' },
  { id: 3, name: 'child 2' },
  { id: 5, name: 'child 4 ' },
  { id: 4, name: 'child 3' },
  { id: 2, name: 'child 1' },
  { id: 1, name: 'parent' }
] */
</script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)